# Can I set Parallel App or Dual App as a default app?

Tags: default-applications, parallel-apps

If more than one browser, media player, PDF reader, etc. is on an Android phone; it asks for the default app for browsing the Internet or opening a web link, playing music, and opening a PDF file.

Like this, there are two WhatsApp (primary WhatsApp and WhatsApp by Parallel App) running on my phone.

How to set WhatsApp by Parallel App as a default WhatsApp?

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp is not a browser or SMS app or contacts app that the phone can allow to select one from many as the default in its category.

Furthermore, your primary WhatsApp is "separate" from WhatsApp in Parallel space. They don't see each other and are not aware that the other exists, making it difficult to select a default.